# Can´t require gems Sinatra

Tags: ruby, macos, sinatra

I'm trying to build a test site using the Sinatra gem but it seems like I can't find the gem when running the server, even though I can find the version through the terminal.

```
`require': cannot load such file -- sinatra (LoadError)
```

I've tried reinstalling all gems, etc but with no success.
Advice?

Running: OS X 10.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to add `gem 'sinatra', '~> 1.4.6'` to your Gemfile and run `bundle install`.

Comment: Tried using SuperUser and reinstalled all gems. Now it works, I thank you for your answer! :)

Comment: If that worked, please mark this question as solved so that others that may have same question can see it in the future.